# SystemC processor in Gazebo/ROS?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to work on a drone which will be controlled by a given processor. I have a SystemC version of the processor, and I'd like to use it to simulate the control of the drone. I was wondering if this could be done in Gazebo. I am familiar with ROS, but I only used it with a raspberry PI in a robot, so I had no custom hardware in the loop.

At the same time, I don't have (yet) any experience in SystemC. According to the person who will provide me with the processor, it is a precise model, to which I provide the SW in binary, and then simulate it for how many ns I want.

So I was wondering, since after all SystemC is a set of C++ classes, would it be possible to integrate this model directly into ROS/Gazebo? So a Gazebo world with a drone in it would take as inputs the commands to the motors (or something like that) from the processor's model, and send back to the model the sensor's readings.

If any of you guys have ever done something like that, I'd be very interested to hear about it! And if not, do you think it is feasible ?

*Edit: since this might require some very specific knowledge, I've asked the same question on stackoverflow (robotics) and on the gazebo forum.
https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/15101/systemc-processor-in-gazebo-ros
http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18425/systemc-processor-in-gazeboros/*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281525/systemc-processor-in-gazebo/ros?/) by [Oddity](https://answers.ros.org/users/29701/oddity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-01**:
could you please link to the other questions? thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Relevant to this question is this paper that shows SystemC and ROS linkage. http://openlib.tugraz.at/download.php?id=598b8711c1957&location=browse

---

Originally posted by [pantelis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33745/pantelis/) with karma: 16 on 2018-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0